# Count how many palindromes in a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, palindrome

I want to find out all possible palindromes that can be possible using substrings from a given string.

```
Example: input = abbcbbd.
Possible palindromes are a,b,b,c,b,b,d,bb,bcb, bbcbb,bb
```

Here is the logic I have implemented:

```
public int palindromeCount(String input) {
    int size = input.length();// all single characters in string are treated as palindromes.
    int count = size;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for(int j=i+2; j<=size; j++) {
            String value = input.substring(i, j);
            String reverse = new StringBuilder(value).reverse().toString();
            if(value.equals(reverse)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here the time complexity is more, how can I improve the performance of this logic?

Comment: what do you mean `all possible palindromes that can be possible from a given string.`? Do you mean by rearranging letters or just strict substrings

Comment: @JClassic, yes  only strict substrings updated my question to make it clear

Comment: What about `bcb` in your example?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes I missed it, included now

Comment: "Here the time complexity is more" More than what? What do you expect the time complexity to be?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, When I used this during a coding exam it failed with performance errors saying timeout, but it did not give sample data to verify my code.

Comment: Sounds like you need to test your code with longer input strings to see what happens.

Comment: Are you sure that you want identical palindromes to show up multiple times, as in your example? I'd expect abbcbbd to yield a, b, c, d, bb, bab, bbb, bcb, bdb, bbbb, bbabb, bbcbb, bbdbb.

Comment: To clarify - do you want to **count** the palindromes, or do you want to **list** them?

Comment: @templatetypedef, I want to count them

Comment: @Dave, I need only substrings of the given input. `bbb` is not a substring of my example

Comment: @learner Do you want to count equal substrings multiple times? For example, do you want to count all 4 b's as four different palindromes?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes I want to count them separately.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some things you can think about when optimizing this algorithm:

1. What are palindromes? A palindrome is a *symmetrical* string, which means it must have a center pivot! The pivot may be one of the following:

   - A letter, as in "a**b**a", or
   - The position between two letters, as in the position between the letters "aa"

That means there are a total of 2*n* − 1 possible pivots.

Then, you can search outwards from each pivot. Here is an example:

- Sample string: "abcba"
- First, let's take a pivot at "c":

  - ab**c**ba → c is a palindrome, then widen your search by 1 on each side.
  - a**bcb**a → bcb is a palindrome, then widen your search by 1 on each side.
  - **abcba** → abcba is a palindrome, so we know there are at least 3 palindromes in the string.
- Continue this with all pivots.

Which this approach, the runtime complexity is *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: How do you determine that the complexity is `O(n^2)`? Can you explain this analysis in more detail? Also, is the OP's solution `O(n^2)`? I see the nested for loops, but there are some additional loops hidden in `substring()` and `reverse()` that make his solution `O(n^3)` if my calculation is correct.

Comment: Yes, i do think OP's answer is `n^3`, because it uses reverse which is `n` at worse. My answer is `n^2` because it has a runtime of at most `n/2` at each pivot, with `2n - 1` pivots

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: The OP's solution is indeed O(n³), for exactly the reason you say. The solution in this answer is O(n²) because the search for a palindrome of length *m* centered at a given pivot takes only O(1), which is possible because it uses the result of the search for a palindrome of length *m*−2 centered at the same pivot.

Answer (score 7):

If you're comfortable busting out some heavyweight data structures, it's possible to do this in time O(n), though I'll admit that this isn't something that will be particularly easy to code up. :-)

We're going to need two tools in order to solve this problem.

**Tool One: Generalized Suffix Trees.** A generalized suffix tree is data structure that, intuitively, is a trie containing all suffixes of two strings S and T, but represented in a more space-efficient way.

**Tool Two: Lowest Common Ancestor Queries.** A lowest common ancestor query structure (or LCA query) is a data structure built around a particular tree. It's designed to efficiently answer queries of the form "given two nodes in the tree, what is their lowest common ancestor?"

Importantly, a generalized suffix tree for two strings of length m can be built in time O(m), and an LCA query can be built in time O(m) such that all queries take time O(1). These are not obvious runtimes; the algorithms and data structures needed here were publishable results when they were first discovered.

Assuming we have these two structures, we can build a third data structure, which is what we'll use to get our final algorithm:

**Tool Three: Longest Common Extension Queries.** A longest common extension query data structure (or LCE query) is a data structure built around two strings S and T. It supports queries of the following form: given an index i into string S and an index j into string T, what is the length of the longest string that appears starting at index i in S and index j in T?

As an example, take these two strings:

```
S: OFFENSE
   0123456

T: NONSENSE
   01234567
```

If we did an LCE query starting at index 3 in string S and index 4 in string T, the answer would be the string ENSE. On the other hand, if we did an LCE query starting at index 4 in string S and index 0 in string T, we'd get back the string N.

(More strictly, the LCE query structure doesn't actually return the actual string you'd find at both places, but rather its length.)

It's possible to build an LCE data structure for a pair of strings S and T of length m in time O(m) so that each query takes time O(1). The technique for doing so involves building a generalized suffix tree for the two strings, then constructing an LCA data structure on top. The key insight is that the LCE starting at position i in string S and j in string T is given by the lowest common ancestor of suffix i of string S and suffix j of string T in the suffix tree.

The LCE structure is extremely useful for this problem. To see why, let's take your sample string `abbcbbd`. Now, consider both that string and its reverse, as shown here:

```
 S: abbcbbd
    0123456

 T: dbbcbba
    0123456
```

Every palindrome in a string takes one of two forms. First, it can be an odd-length palindrome. A palindrome like that has some central character c, plus some "radius" stretching out forwards and backwards from that center. For example, the string `bbcbb` is an odd-length palindrome with center `c` and radius `bb`.

We can count up how many odd-length palindromes there are in a string by using LCE queries. Specifically, build an LCE query structure over both the string and its reverse. Then, for each position within the original string, ask for the LCE of that position in the original string and its corresponding position in the mirrored string. This will give you the longest odd-length palindrome centered at that point. (More specifically, it'll give you the length of the radius plus one, since the character itself will always match at those two points). Once we know the *longest* odd-length palindrome centered at that position in the string, we can count the *number* of odd-length palindromes centered at that position in the string: that will be equal to all the ways we can take that longer palindrome and shorten it by cutting off the front and back character.

With this in mind, we can count all the odd-length palindromes in the string as follows:

```
for i from 0 to length(S) - 1:
    total += LCE(i, length(S) - 1 - i)
```

The other class of palindromes are even-length palindromes, which don't have a center and instead consist of two equal radii. We can also find these using LCE queries, except instead of looking at some position `i` and its corresponding position in the reversed string, we'll look at position `i` in the original string and the place that corresponds to index `i` - 1 in the reversed string. That can be done here:

```
for i from 1 to length(S) - 1:
    total += LCE(i, length(S) - i)
```

Overall, this solution

- Constructs an LCE query structure from the original string and the reversed string. Reversing the string takes time O(m) and building the LCE query structure takes time O(m). Total time for this step: **O(m)**.
- Makes 2m - 1 total queries to the LCE structure. Each query takes time O(1). Total time for this step: **O(m)**.

I'm fairly certain it's possible to achieve this runtime without using such heavyweight tools, but this at least shows that a linear-time solution exists.

Hope this helps!